# axis numbers fall outside of the lattice plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, x-axis

When I plot my lattice graph, the x-axis value of 100000 falls outside of the plot. I don't want to make the number size smaller. Anything I could do to make this work?

code:

```
bwplot(dfmh2$Period~dfmh2$Intensity|dfmh2$microhabitat, #temperature difference low over day period
       par.settings = my_settings,
       par.strip.text = list(cex =1.7),
       scales = list(x = list(font=1,cex=2),y = list(cex = 1.8)),
       ylab= list(label = "Period of Day", fontsize = 25), xlab= list(label = "Light intensity", fontsize = 25), 
       main= list(label  =  "B) Light intenstiy (lux)", cex= 2))
```

My plot looks like this now:
[image]

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing `dput(dfmh2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try tuning

```
> lattice.options("skip.boundary.labels")
$skip.boundary.labels
[1] 0.02
```